# android facebook hash key in cygwin

Tags: android, linux, facebook, unix

I try to create hash key for my android app using this command

```
keytool.exe -exportcert -alias mykeystorealias -keystore "C:/Projects/mykeystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
```

But after entering password and copy paste generated key on [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) my key didn't work

I download Cygwin and I want to try generating the same hash key using Cygwin.

I'm not very familiar with unix can anyone help me and give me Cygwni-linux interpretation for (I read that linux and windows hash key can generate different results):

```
    keytool.exe -exportcert -alias mykeystorealias -keystore "C:/Projects/mykeystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
```

Thanks